# SPU Instruction Pointer

Tags: playstation3, spu

I've been searching through the entire manuals and I can't find a single mention of the Instruction Pointer. I need this for a SPU program that I'm writing. Maybe it has a different name? Can anyone tell me how I can access the address of the instruction that is to be executed? Thanks in advance for your help.
UPDATE: Apperantly it's called the Program Counter, but how can I access it from within my SPU Program?

Comment: On most architectures it's called the Program Counter (PC) - Intel's a little non-conformist in its nomenclature in this regard.

Comment: Thanks a million! This is really embarrassing, but I've only done assembly coding on the x86.
But I have another question: Is it possible to read it without the SPU being stopped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get the instruction pointer, you can do it in assembly:

```
brsl r<n>, .+4
```

This loads the address of the next instruction into register `r<n>`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can get the next instruction by executing a [`spe_context_run`](http://moss.csc.ncsu.edu/%7Emueller/cluster/ps3/SDK3.0/docs/accessibility/libspe/cplsrunc/spe_context_run.html) operation:

`int spe_context_run(spe_context_ptr_t spe, unsigned int *entry, unsigned int runflags, void *argp, void *envp, spe_stop_info_t *stopinfo)`

> `entry`
>
> Input: The entry point, that is, the initial value of the SPU
> instruction pointer, at which the SPE program should start executing.
> If the value of entry is SPE_DEFAULT_ENTRY, the entry point for the
> SPU main program is obtained from the loaded SPE image. This is
> usually the local store address of the initialization function crt0
> (see Cell Broadband Engine Programming Handbook, Objects, Executables,
> and SPE Loading).
>
> Output: The SPU instruction pointer at the moment the SPU stopped
> execution, that is, the local store address of the next instruction
> that would be have been executed.
>
> This parameter can be used, for example, to allow the SPE program to
> "pause" and request some action from the PPE thread, for example,
> performing an I/O operation. After this PPE-side action has been
> completed, you can continue the SPE program calling spe_context_run
> again without changing entry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I would like to do this on the SPU, whereas spe_context_run runs a context and is on the PPU.

Comment: Ah, so you are *running* an SPU program, and want to get the instruction pointer? Please update your question and mention it.

Comment: Yes. Sorry for not being clear on that. Is there a way? From what I read from the instructions the SPU has to be disabled in order to read the SPU_NPC, but I would like to read it within my SPU Program.